# Odd behavior in as.POSIXct: date changes

Tags: r, date, time

How is this not a bug?

```
as.POSIXct(as.Date("2013/01/01"))
```

Result:

```
[1] "2012-12-31 19:00:00 EST"
```

Comment: Why not just `as.POSIXct("2013/01/01")`? Also, that error doesn't reproduce for me.

Comment: Great point, I think I can drop as.Date() -- I was just borrowing someone else's code.  I wonder if the bug could be a function of my OS  - Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calls the `as.POSIXct.Date` method, which is

```
function (x, ...) 
.POSIXct(unclass(x) * 86400)
```

Note that there is no possibility to pass a time zone to `.POSIXct` although it has such a parameter:

```
function (xx, tz = NULL) 
structure(xx, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = tz)
```

So this happens:

```
structure(unclass(as.Date("2013/01/01")) * 86400, 
          class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST")
#[1] "2012-12-31 19:00:00 EST"
```

Workaround if you want to convert `Date`s:

```
structure(unclass(as.Date("2013/01/01")) * 86400, 
          class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")
#"2013-01-01 GMT"
```

Or modify `as.POSIXct.Date` to

```
function (x, tz=NULL,...)  .POSIXct(unclass(x) * 86400, tz = tz)
```

Comment: another workaround: `as.POSIXct(format(as.Date("2013/01/01")), tz="GMT")`